# How to to check image nil when access to camera and press cancel on camera

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How to check  image nil when access to camera and press cancel on camera

I’m tested
First step

1. Press take photo button

   - access camera

     2. Press cancel  I’m get value on output panel

        - Check image take photo ==> Optional(UIImagePickerController: 0x107879a00)
     3. Press save button photo on project
        I’m getting value nil

        - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 2019-07-05 08:52:24.667938+0700 MyProject[2307:786209] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I’m tested
the second step

1. ### Take photo

   2.press use photo on the ​camera

   - Take photo press use photo  on camera

     > Check image take photo ==> Optional(UIImagePickerController: 0x10286ca00)

I want to check case cancel on camera and go back press save button on the project

> How to fix….this case
>   My code below

Take photo

```
 @IBAction func takePhotoReturnOfSealButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock.delegate = self
        imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock,animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Check image take photo ==> \(String(describing: imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock))")
    }//takePhotoReturnOfSealButton
```

Save photo

```
@IBAction func saveImageToDevice(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Save photo to device not success have nil value
        if(imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock == nil){
            showAlert(title: "No Have Photo", message: "Please take photo")
            print("Check image cannot save ==> \(String(describing: imagePickerStoreListReturnSealLock))")
        }else{
//          Save photo to device success
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(showImageTakePhotoReturnOfSeal.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            print("Check image Save to device ==> \(String(describing: showImageTakePhotoReturnOfSeal))")
        }
    }//saveImageToDevice
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you cancel the Image Picker a delegate method is been called -

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    //Perform your action when cancel has been pressed
}
```

This method is been called when Image is been picked -

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
   if picker == imagePicker {
        //Save your image
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Just remember to define this above -

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
imagePicker.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on cancel of image picker, following delegate method will be called:

```
public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and when you select an image, Following delegate method will be called:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let image : UIImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)//to save image in saved photo album
        }
```

Hope this helps